# Bounce routine with random walk in Netlogo 3D

Tags: netlogo

I'm having trouble coding a bounce routine with a random walk in Netlogo. I want to have agents do a random walk in a unidirectional current (the code for this bit is not correct, but is a functional placeholder). I also need to prevent agents from entering a seabed feature, delineated by an RGB pcolor. Here's my effort:

```
to move-resources
ask resources [
right random 45
left random 45
tilt-up random 45
tilt-down random 45
fd 1
;;; simulated current in one direction:
set heading 90
set pitch 0
set roll 0
fd 1
while [ any? patches in-radius 1 with [ pcolor = [218 160 62]] ]  [
let nearest-patch min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = [218 160 62]])[distance 
myself] ;;; find the closest sandy patch
face nearest-patch ;; face that patch
set heading heading - 180 ;; face away from that patch
fd 1 ;; move away from that patch
]
]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for missing a trivial mistake, but my problem was simply the use of:

```
set heading heading - 180
```

When in 3D I should've used (for a horizontally-oriented seabed):

```
set pitch pitch - 180
```